# How do I change the temporary server path name of a website?

Tags: cpanel

This may not be the correct forum for this (if so please direct me to the correct one). I am building a website that was set up using C-Panel.

The temporary URL for the site is http://174.121.46.122/~flowerwo/

For most intents and purposes this is fine but there is conflict with the tilde (~) portion of the url and the CMS system (Expression Engine) that I am using. Is there a way to change the temporary URL to something like: http://174.121.46.122/_flowerwo/ or http://174.121.46.122/-flowerwo/?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it usually some folder in your home directory inside the machine. So do a ssh into that machine and find out. One way to confirm this theory is by opening the httpd.conf. usually located in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and look for something like userdir . Look up at the httpd.apache.org docs section and see the directive corresponding to home directory. And then remove  that entry in your machine httpd.conf or from one of included conf files. Now move the content of those under that dir to your dir specifed by document root. This should solve your problem.

HTH

Comment: Is there any way to do this just using cpanel?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why the above answered was marked as correct, but it is dead wrong.

The tilde+username system is usually (especially in cpanel) set up with `mod_userdir` Apache module.

I don't know if you can make the module use a different character, but regardless the case, there is no folder named `~username`.

So, to answer your question, to do what you want, I would advise creating a folder somewhere on the main server (eg: `http://174.121.46.122/_flowerwo/`) and put an `.htaccess` inside it with a rule rewriting requests to the folder to `~flowerwo`.

PS: It is important that you *rewrite* the URLs not *redirect*, because redirects will cause the user to end up on the `~flowerwo` part, which I presume is something you wouldn't want.